# return files on samba file server

Tags: samba4

I use **Ubuntu** 14.04 x64bit Server as a Samba File Server.

I executed:

```
find /home/samba/* -type f -mtime -11 -exec mv /home/samba/milan {} \;
```

I wanted to copy files, ***not move***.

How to bring back all the files on the old place where they were previously.

Answer (score 0):

That command will have matched multiple files under `/home/samba`. The first in the list returned from `find` will have been replaced by the contents of `/home/samba/milan`. The rest of the files that were passed to `-exec mv ...` would of given a `mv: no such file or directory` error. (This is because the first `-exec mv` moved `/home/samba/milan` to the first matched file and so the subsequent ones will have got the error).

In effect you only have to restore the file returned from

```
find /home/samba/* -type f -mtime -11 | head -1
```

(which will have to be fetched from a backup).